# Spyder terminates without apparant reason

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

For some reason spyder terminates without reason

When run using anaconda prompt spyder leaves a termination message.

Is it possible to fix this?

```
(base) C:\Users\Rafael Zanzoori>spyder
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\Users\nwani\Downloads\mc3\conda-bld\zeromq_1531316860385\work\src\signaler.cpp:379)
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\Users\nwani\Downloads\mc3\conda-bld\zeromq_1531316860385\work\src\signaler.cpp:379)
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\Users\nwani\Downloads\mc3\conda-bld\zeromq_1531316860385\work\src\signaler.cpp:379)

(base) C:\Users\Rafael Zanzoori>
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is usually a problem with your firewall or antivirus. Please deactivate them and try again.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time. I did as per your suggestion: disabled windows firewall / antivirus but after a few hours of PC inactivity - Spyder terminates. On another PC it doesn't happen. Are there any logs from which i can understand what causes the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with the help of god i found the solutuion :)

I had an application running called NetWorx that was causing the problem.
I uninstalled it yesterday and left spyder running and now a day after spyder is still running.

I guess a general solution for spyder terminating is to find and try to disable any network related application and in my case networx in particular.

I found the solution by searching in google:
"Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer"

And then found the solution in the following link:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9236